# Combining two select queries into one efficiently

Tags: mysql

**user**

```
id   |  name
1    |  A
2    |  B
```

**article**

```
id   | title | descritption
1    | wx    | xyz
2    | yz    | abc
```

**article_rating**

```
article_id(article->id)  |  given_by(user->id)  |  given_rating
   1                              2                  4
   2                              1                  3
```

**saved_article**

```
article_id(article->id)  |  saved_by(user->id) 
   1                              2
```

I'm changing some buttons and icons depending on whether a user has rated/ saved an article or not. I'm using two select queries for that:

**rated or not**

```
SELECT given_rating as rating 
FROM article_rating 
WHERE  given_by=? AND article_id=?
```

**saved or not**

```
SELECT saved_by as saved 
FROM saved_article 
WHERE  saved_by=? AND article_id=?
```

So my question is how can i combine both into one mysql query efficiently??

Comment: If we were to agree that something was missing from this question, what might that something be?

Comment: @Strawberry A premature answer by yours truly?  I mean, yeah, there are a bunch of holes in the question, but that wouldn't stop Gordon Linoff, right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but then again, what would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you *could* try to write a single query based on a union of the two tables, e.g.

```
SELECT val, source
FROM
(
    SELECT NULL AS saved_by, given_by, given_rating AS val, 'given_rating' AS source
    FROM article_rating
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL AS given_by, saved_by, 'saved_by'
    FROM saved_article
) t
WHERE
    (source = 'given_rating' AND given_by = ? AND article_id = ?) OR
    (source = 'saved_by' AND (saved_by = ? OR saved_by IS NULL) AND article_id = ?);
```

I use a common trick here, which is to introduce a computed column `source` into the union query.  Then, in the `WHERE` clause, we can refer to it to decide which set of restrictions we need to apply.

Whether the above query even makes any sense depends on a few things, most important that `given_rating` and `saved_by` belong together in a single column report.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tim Biegeleisen. Unfortunately, Got some error "unknown column 'given_by' and also the 'article_id'".

Comment: And Is there a way to get the `given_rating` and `saved_by` results differently???

Comment: Thanks again @TIM Biegeleisen. I had to modify  little bit to make it work  (updated your answer).